# $scope.$on & controller load timing/speeds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I'm curious about the timing of when Angular controllers are loaded versus $scope/event listeners in those controllers.  **Could someone provide documentation or an explanation how this works?**

I've looked for a while, and could not find a clear answer on this.

I have this example where I load filter options from a database, and $emit to a parent controller, then $broadcast an event to the other controllers when this occurs. (Code is abbreviated)

FilterController.js

```
app.controller("FilterController", ["$scope", "$q", function($scope, $q) {

    (function getInitialFilters() {
        $q.all([
            // Few promises that call the database for information and sets filters
        ]).then(function(){
            // After all the promises finish, $emit event to parent controller, 
            // AppController
            $scope.$emit("heyAppControllerFiltersHaveLoaded")  
        })    
    }();

}])
```

AppController.js (parent controller of FilterController and DashboardController)

```
app.controller("AppController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

    $scope.$on("heyAppControllerFiltersHaveLoaded", function() {
        $scope.$broadcast("allChildControllersFiltersHaveLoaded");
        console.log('broadcast sent');
    });
}]);
```

The problem is, when the $broadcast occurs, the $scope.$on / event listener in a child controller misses it, even though it seems the controller has loaded AND the $emit and $broadcast occurs after the longest roundtrip to the database finishes.  (Granted, it's not that long of a trip)

DashboardController.js

```
app.controller("DashboardController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    console.log('DashboardController loaded');

    $scope.$on("allChildControllersFiltersHaveLoaded", function() {
        console.log('listener listened');
        doSomeStuffWithFilters();
    });
}]);
```

The console prints out in the following order:

"DashboardController loaded"

"broadcast sent"

The quick fix solution I found here was to add a 500ms timeout to the $broadcast, and THEN the DashboardController catches the event.

**My question though, does the controller load, and then takes a while to add a $scope.$on / event listener?  Even longer than a short roundtrip to a database and longer than registering an $emit and $broadcast in other controllers? Or how does the timing work here?**

Comment: This is a great example of why building directives with isolated scope is such a great idea...you can push data down without worrying about race conditions.

Comment: most likely a better way to do this than having this circuit of events. A `resolve` in router would remove need for all of this for example. Also suspect you aren't using a service for the data either. A service would allow you to share one promise across these components.

Comment: Also, if you have to reach up with an event, consider passing along a callback function instead of broadcasting back down.

Comment: @charlietfl I am using a service for the data, sorry omitted that part, each database call is a promise (say 4 here), but that is an interesting idea to use one promise for possibly all of these promises, and run the function on resolve without the listener

Comment: @DavidL what would be a good way to use a directive here?  i understand that in isolate scope, a change in the controller scope goes ahead and updates the bound values in the directive's isolate scope, but here, I am waiting for the FilterController to finish the database calls, so I can run another database call with all these new values from the responses. 

For the callback, are you suggesting to pass up a callback function as the second argument, so that when it does reach the top, you then call that function?  Just making sure I understand you correctly :)

Comment: @devonJS It's hard to tell from your example, but it seems like binding the filters down the scope chain so that when they resolve, they are available throughout the isolate scope chain would be ideal.  You can place a watch at the top to perform an action once the filters are loaded.  As for the callback, if you stick to events you can pass a callback as the second argument, correct.  When you receive the event, you simply invoke the callback.  That would prevent you from needing to then broadcast an event back down the stack.